# FS2 stream run till the end of InputStream

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, fs2

I'm very new to FS2 and need some help about the desing. I'm trying to design a stream which will pull the chunks from the underlying `InputStream` till it's over. Here is what I tried:

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream, InputStream}

import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.IO._

object Fs2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val is = new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/my-file.mf"))
    val stream = fs2.Stream.eval(read(is))
    stream.compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
  }

  def read(is: InputStream): IO[Array[Byte]] = IO {
    val buf = new Array[Byte](4096)
    is.read(buf)
    println(new String(buf))
    buf
  }
}
```

And the program prints the only first chunk. This is reasonable. But I want to find a way to "signal" where to stop reading and where to not stop. I mean keep calling `read(is)` till its end. Is there a way to achieve that?

I also tried `repeatEval(read(is))`  but it keeps reading forever... I need something in between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`fs2.io.readInputStream`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-io_2.12/0.10.1/fs2-io_2.12-0.10.1-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/io/index.html#readInputStream[F[_]](fis:F[java.io.InputStream],chunkSize:Int,closeAfterUse:Boolean)(implicitF:cats.effect.Sync[F]):fs2.Stream[F,Byte]) or [`fs2.io.readInputStreamAsync`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-io_2.12/0.10.1/fs2-io_2.12-0.10.1-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/io/index.html#readInputStreamAsync[F[_]](fis:F[java.io.InputStream],chunkSize:Int,closeAfterUse:Boolean)(implicitF:cats.effect.Effect[F],implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):fs2.Stream[F,Byte]). The former blocks the current thread; the latter blocks a thread in the `ExecutionContext`. For example:

```
val is: InputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/my-file.mf"))
val stream = fs2.io.readInputStreamAsync(IO(is), 128)
```

Comment: Coool, thanks much. The implementation gave me an idea about how to chunk in custom way (I need a bit more complicated chunk stratgegy than chunk size). Unfortunately, can give +1 just once :)